# C++: Strange multiple definition errors and problems with

Tags: c++

My first, immediate problem is with many strange errors that look like this:

```
In function ZN6BeingC2Ev:
multiple definition of 'area'
first defined here
```

I am writing a basic pathfinding system and I have two classes:

-Area: Areas describe the 2D grid of walls and open spaces that beings navigate through.

-Graph: Every being capable of pathfinding has its own Graph, and each of those graph objects need to get a part of the layout of the world grid from the currently active Area.

So all Graph objects need to know about *area, which in main() is allocated by the usual area = new Area();

But I can't declare Area *area in main.cpp because Graphs wouldn't be able to see it, and its methods won't be able to read it.

So I tried to declare *area in area.h (shown below). My intention was that because Graph #includes "area.h", area would be known to Graph. This causes my my multiple definitions problem.

I am unsure what exactly the problem is, since I am sure I did not define Area in any way outside of its own header file, and partly because my IDE points me to seemingly unrelated functions when I click the error message for the source of the multiple definition.

So my second question: In the interest of avoiding such an error, is there a better structure that will give Graph knowledge of Area objects and access to their contents?

Below is code which I hope demonstrates my intentions, please let me know if anything necessary has been omitted.

area.h

```
#ifndef AREA_H_INCLUDED
#define AREA_H_INCLUDED

class Area
{
    std::vector<int>wallmap;
    ...
} *area;

#endif // AREA_H_INCLUDED
```

graph.h

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H_INCLUDED
#define GRAPH_H_INCLUDED

#include "area.h"

class Graph
{
    ...
};

#endif // GRAPH_H_INCLUDED
```

graph.cpp (The problem is in the switch part)

```
std::vector<Node*>Graph::RequestPath(int startX, int startY, int destX, int destY);
{
    for(std::vector<Node*>::iterator it = nodeGraph.begin(); it != nodeGraph.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->heuristic = std::abs(destX-startX) + std::abs(destY-startY);

        switch(area->wallmap[(*it)->id]) // **I need Graphs to know about the wallmap vector in Area, here for example.**
        {
            ....
        }

    (*it)->fValue = (*it)->heuristic + (*it)->moveCost;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "area.h"

int main()
{
    ...
    area = new Area();
    area->Init();

    ...
    delete area;
    ...
}
```

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Code that just demonstrates your intentions is unlikely to demonstrate your *problem* unless your intentions are fundamentally wrong. We need a [mcve] here.

Comment: You're defining a global variable in a header file, and every translation unit (cpp file) that includes it is going to get a copy of this variable. Don't define a global variable in a header file. Try not to use globals at all, actually.

Comment: `ZN6BeingC2Ev` doesn't look like a properly formatted GCC-mangled name. There are at least two characters missing after the `2`. I concur that a MCVE is needed here, but besides that, also the *actual error messages*, not words that "look like" it.

Comment: As an addendum to what @GManNickG said: If you _do_ want to use a global variable, declare it as `extern` in the header, and define it in the source file.  This way, you only have one definition, and the linker knows that every use of it refers specifically to that one definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment by @GManNickG, the problem lies with the use of `area` as a variable in:

```
class Area
{
    std::vector<int>wallmap;
    ...
} *area;
```

Every compilation unit that `#include`s the .h file will define that variable, which leads to the multiple definition error at link time.

I suggest using a function to get the necessary pointer instead of using a global variable.

```
class Area
{
    std::vector<int>wallmap;
    ...
};

Area* getArea();
```

Implement it in the .cpp file that implements the member functions of `Area`, just to keep related definitions together

Then, you can use the function wherever you were using the global variable.

If you must use a global variable, which I strongly advise against, you can use:

```
class Area
{
    std::vector<int>wallmap;
    ...
};

extern Area* area;
```

and make sure that `area` is defined in the .cpp file that implements the member functions of `Area`, just to keep related definitions together.